# How to use chart data from main thread rather than the JavaFX thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, charts, javafx-8

I would like to create a simple method that plots a line chart given an object that contains the points to be displayed and some other chart attributes (like the chart title) and saves it as an image.

Here is a code example:

```
public class MyChartApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ChartData chartData = generateChartData();
        WritableImage image = constructChartImage(chartData);
        save(image, "chart.png");
    }

    public static WritableImage constructChartImage(ChartData data) {
        // code to be written
    }

    private static ChartData generateChartData() {
        ChartData chartData = new ChartData();
        chartData.setValuesX(new double[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
        chartData.setValuesY(new double[]{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1});
        chartData.setChartTitle("My Chart");
        return chartData;
    }

    public static void save(WritableImage image, String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", new File(path));
    }

    /**
     * JavaFX application used to construct the chart.
     */
    public static class MyChart extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

            // Somehow retrieve chartData passed to constructChartImage()
            ChartData chartData = ... 

            //defining the axes
            final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
            final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

            //creating the chart
            final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                    new LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

            lineChart.setAnimated(false);
            lineChart.setTitle(chartData.getChartTitle());

            //defining a series
            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

            //populating the series with data
            addAll(series, chartData);

            Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
            lineChart.getData().add(series);


            lineChart.applyCss();
            lineChart.layout();

            stage.setScene(scene);

            WritableImage image = scene.snapshot(null);

            // somehow pass the image object to constructChartImage().
        }

        // utility methods for adding data to the chart //

        private static void addAll(XYChart.Series series, ChartData chartData) {
            double[] valuesX = chartData.getValuesX();
            double[] valuesY = chartData.getValuesY();
            for (int i = 0; i < valuesX.length; i++) {
                add(series, valuesX[i], valuesY[i]);
            }
        }

        private static void add(XYChart.Series series, double x, double y) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(x,y));
        }

    }

    public static class ChartData {
        private double[] valuesX;
        private double[] valuesY;
        private String chartTitle;

        public String getChartTitle() {
            return chartTitle;
        }

        public void setChartTitle(String chartTitle) {
            this.chartTitle = chartTitle;
        }

        public double[] getValuesX() {
            return valuesX;
        }

        public void setValuesX(double[] valuesX) {
            this.valuesX = valuesX;
        }

        public double[] getValuesY() {
            return valuesY;
        }

        public void setValuesY(double[] valuesY) {
            this.valuesY = valuesY;
        }
    }

}
```

Although the idea might have seemed simple, the implementation is not. I do not know how to pass the chart data from the main application to the JavaFX application. Generating the data inside the JavaFX thread (for example by using the `generateChartData()` method) is not a preferred solution.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523280/how-to-pass-data-from-java-program-to-javafx-application-chart) but the suggested solution did not worked for me. It also uses static shared fields which I think is not a good practice. In addition, my case is simpler because I do not want to update the data over time.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? In the usual use case, the "main application" *is* the JavaFX application, and you just create the chart and the data in the `start()` method in the usual way. If you have a pressing need to set things up differently (which is really quite difficult), you need to explain why and how you are organizing your application.

Comment: The way my application is structured makes it easier if I just pass somehow the data to the JavaFX application rather than generating the data within the JavaFX application.

Comment: "Easier" in the sense that you don't know how to do it???? You're sort of missing the point. The `start(...)` method in a JavaFX application basically replaces the `main()` method. Just move the content of your `main()` method to `start()` (though you need to be aware that `start()` is on the FX Application thread). Your structure will not work, because you need to create a `Scene` before the FX toolkit is started.

Comment: If I do that, I am afraid that there will be performance issues because my whole application will run in the JavaFX application thread instead of the main Java thread.

Comment: Then just start another thread in `start()` and run the non-UI code there. Again, the `start()` method in the `Application` class is the place where the application starts.

Comment: OK will try it. Although in my particular case your solution will work, I believe that this question still stands and needs an answer. There is got to be a way to pass an object from the main thread to JavaFX thread.

Comment: That last statement doesn't even make sense. You don't pass data "between threads", you pass data to objects via method calls. So what *object* are you meaning you want to pass the data to? You generally don't get access to the `Application` instance that is created on starting the FX toolkit other than from inside its `start()` method, so the general solution is that you do whatever you need in the `start()` method. If you just want to start the FX toolkit for "future use", see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739199 (though there is no reason to go to these lengths imho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is just to create a chart and save it to an image file, why don't you just do

```
public class MyChartApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // other app code...

        MyChart myChart = new MyChart();
        ChartData chartData = myChart.generateChartData();
        WritableImage image = myChart.constructChartImage(chartData);
        myChart.save(image, "chart.png");

        // other app code...
    }

    public static class MyChart {

        public WritableImage constructChartImage(ChartData data) {
            //defining the axes
            final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
            final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

            //creating the chart
            final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                    new LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

            lineChart.setAnimated(false);
            lineChart.setTitle(chartData.getChartTitle());

            //defining a series
            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

            //populating the series with data
            addAll(series, chartData);

            Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
            lineChart.getData().add(series);


            lineChart.applyCss();
            lineChart.layout();

            WritableImage image = scene.snapshot(null);

            return image ;
        }

        private ChartData generateChartData() {
            ChartData chartData = new ChartData();
            chartData.setValuesX(new double[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
            chartData.setValuesY(new double[]{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1});
            chartData.setChartTitle("My Chart");
            return chartData;
        }

        public void save(WritableImage image, String path) throws IOException {
            BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", new File(path));
        }

        private void addAll(XYChart.Series series, ChartData chartData) {
            double[] valuesX = chartData.getValuesX();
            double[] valuesY = chartData.getValuesX();
            for (int i = 0; i < valuesX.length; i++) {
                add(series, valuesX[i], valuesY[i]);
            }
        }

        private void add(XYChart.Series series, double x, double y) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(x,y));
        }

    }

    public static class ChartData {
        private double[] valuesX;
        private double[] valuesY;
        private String chartTitle;

        public String getChartTitle() {
            return chartTitle;
        }

        public void setChartTitle(String chartTitle) {
            this.chartTitle = chartTitle;
        }

        public double[] getValuesX() {
            return valuesX;
        }

        public void setValuesX(double[] valuesX) {
            this.valuesX = valuesX;
        }

        public double[] getValuesY() {
            return valuesY;
        }

        public void setValuesY(double[] valuesY) {
            this.valuesY = valuesY;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This works fine for the simple example code I posted but not for the complex application I am working on. I would like the JavaFX application to be an extension of my main application and not my main application.

Comment: @pgmank See update (which simply factors the chart-specific code into a class separate from the application class).